# Problem on Galois theory and irreducible polynomial

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p,q$ be primes, estimate the degree $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]{2}\cdot\sqrt[q]{2}):\Bbb Q]$ and prove that the polynomial $X^q-2$ is irreducible in the ring $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]{2})[X]$

I found this problem on mathematical competition without any solution and it would be very interesting if we can find a proof for this.

Comment: In lightly editing your question, I see that you have a dot between the two radicals. Did you mean a comma (virgule) or did you mean the product of the two radicals?

Comment: it's the product of the two radicals

Comment: I’ve edited to put in a central dot. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Of course $p$ and $q$ are different primes. Then $\sqrt[p]2\cdot\sqrt[q]2=2^{(q+p)/pq}$, and so your big field is certainly contained in $\Bbb Q(2^{1/pq})$. On the other hand, since $p+q$ is relatively prime to $pq$, there are integers $A$ and $B$ with $A(p+q)+Bpq=1$. Now, $2^B\cdot\bigl(2^{(p+q)/pq}\bigr)^A=2^{(Bpq+A(p+q))pq}=2^{1/pq}$. That is, if $\mu=2^{1/pq}$ and $\rho=2^{(q+p)/pq}$, we have $\mu=2^B\rho^A$, so that the opposite inclusion $\Bbb Q(2^{1/pq})\subset\Bbb Q(2^{1/p + 1/q})$ also holds, and the degree over $\Bbb Q$ is exactly $pq$.

For your second question, I believe that the analysis of @oxeimon is just right.

Maybe I could say that a much more advanced approach, embedding $\Bbb Q$ into $\Bbb Q_2$, the $2$-adic numbers, and the very simplest properties of the Newton Polygon, would get your answer much sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $p\ne q$... I claim the degree is $pq$ (and thus $X^q-2$ is irreducible over $Q(\sqrt[p]{2})[X]$).

First note $[Q(\sqrt[q]{2}:Q] = q$, since $X^q-2$ is irreducible over $Q$ by Eisenstein. (Same with $X^p-2$)

The field $Q(\sqrt[p]{2},\sqrt[q]{2})$ is the compositum of $Q(\sqrt[p]{2})$ and $Q(\sqrt[q]{2})$. Let $L := Q(\sqrt[p]{2})\cap Q(\sqrt[q]{2})$, then its well known that
$$[Q(\sqrt[p]{2},\sqrt[q]{2}):L] = [Q(\sqrt[p]{2}):L]\cdot[Q(\sqrt[q]{2}):L]$$

Thus it suffices to prove that $L = Q$, but this is clear from the fact that $[L:Q]$ divides both $[Q(\sqrt[q]{2}):Q] = q$ and $[Q(\sqrt[p]{2}):Q] = p$, and $q,p$ are coprime, so $[L:Q] = 1$.

Comment: $[L:Q]=1$ implies that $L=Q$?

Comment: OP has explained that he meant the product of $\sqrt[p]2$ and $\sqrt[q]2$ to generate the big field, so I’m not sure your analysis is completely on the mark.

Comment: IMO you need to exercise a little bit more care. If $Q(a)\cap Q(b)=L$ it  does not follow that $[Q(a,b):L]=[Q(a):L]\cdot [Q(b):L]$. A standard counterexample is the case when $a$ and $b$ are distinct cube roots of $2$. Then $Q(a,b)$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$, hence a degree six extension. But $Q(a)\cap Q(b)=Q$ and $[Q(a):Q]=[Q(b):Q]=3$. What saves the day here is that $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Because $Q(a)$ and $Q(b)$ are certainly intermediate extensions we have $p=[Q(a):Q]\mid [Q(a,b):Q]$ and $q=[Q(b):Q]\mid [Q(a,b):Q]$. Hence $pq\mid [Q(a,b):Q]$. Clearly $[Q(a,b):Q]\le pq$, and you are done.

Comment: In general you need linearly disjoint extensions over $L$ for the degree calculation to go as simply as this.