# Irreducible polynomial $X^q-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Prove that the polynomial $X^q-2$ is irreducible in the ring $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[p]{2})[X]$

What method i can use for proving, that this polynomial is irreducible in this specific ring?

Comment: What are $q$ and $p$?

Comment: It would not be true if $p \mid q$, for example.

Comment: sorry i forgot to refer that $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers not the same values (distinct)

Comment: [Did you not already ask this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1369148/11619)? Please explain why you break the rule not to repost the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E = \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt[p]{2})$ and $F= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]{2})$ be the respevtive field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ by the roots of $X^p-2$ and $X^q-2$. As $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then the field extension $EF = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\sqrt[q]{2})$ has degree $q$ over $E$. As the polynomial $X^q-2$ has as root $\sqrt[q]{2}$, and also has degree $q$, then it is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[q]{2}$, meaning it is irreducible.

Comment: Does your argument require that $p$ and $q$ are primes?  All I see is that they only need to be coprime integers.  Just curious.

Comment: We can't use Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, as long as $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers, this works.

Comment: @ParisD.R.Y. Eisenstain's Criterion needs a prime in the domain in question. here $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ is a field, so $2$ isn't prime. You would need a subring R of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ for which, $2$ is prime and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) = Frac(R)$.

Comment: why we use the fact that $EF = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2},\sqrt[q]{2})$ has degree $q$ over $E$ . We need this for the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @ParisD.R.Y. Yes we do. If $EF/E$ had less degree, then, because $q$ is prime, it would mean that $EF=E$, meaning that $X^q - 2$ would have a root in $E$ (namely $\sqrt[q]{2})$ ), so it isn't irreducible. Even if $q$ wasn't prime, this would mean that $X^q - 2$ isn't the minimal polynomial (the degree of the polynomial always coincides with the degree of the extension), so it would reduce (maybe in non-linear factors).